# dired+ is not invoked by default

Tags: dired

When I type `C-x d` for the first time after starting emacs I get regular *dired*, not *dired+* view. If I execute `M-x diredp-dired-for-files` I get *dired+* view of the directory, **and** every `C-x d` after that opens *dired+* view of any directory I visit.  Also if *dired+* package was updated from `list-packages` then `C-x d` invokes *dired+* automatically even the first time and without me having to execute `diredp-dired-for-files`.  Why doesn't *dired+* get invoked automatically on the first and subsequent `C-x d` until I manually invoke it as `diredp-dired-for-files`?  Is this how it supposed to work?

**Edit** I forgot to mention, `package-initialize` is the first command in my `init.el`. In fact, the packaging system takes care of this

```
;; Added by Package.el.  This must come before configurations of
;; installed packages.  Don't delete this line.  If you don't want it,
;; just comment it out by adding a semicolon to the start of the line.
;; You may delete these explanatory comments.
(package-initialize)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are using the package system (e.g. MELPA), make sure you have used `(package-initialize`.
- Alternatively (especially if you are not using the package system): Put `dired+.el` (or `dired+.elc`) in a directory that is in your `load-path`, and put `(require 'dired+)` in your init file.

The reason Dired+ was not available from the outset is that it was not loaded by default.  The above instructions should fix that. The reason that Dired+ was available after you used a Dired+ command was that the command you used was autoloaded, meaning that you could invoke it before Dired+ was loaded, and invoking it automatically loaded Dired+. Once it was loaded it was available from then on.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not so simple because I do use the package system and  (package-initialize) is the first command in my init.el, but this doesn't help in this case.  Moreover, `package-selected-packages` list includes `dired+`.  I assume that should guarantee dired+ is loaded by default.

Comment: @dmakarov: did you also include the `(require 'dired+)` line that Drew mentioned?

Comment: Indeed, adding `(require 'dired+)` solves this problem.